# How to use promises to push values to an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that calls an exported async/await function  I need to push the value returned in an array and return it but I get an empty array I know I have to use a promise but can't figure out how to do it correctly.

```
function calculatePrice() {
  let nearestPickUps = findNearestPickups();
  let prices = [];
  nearestPickUps.forEach(loc => {
    let pickup = loc.nearest.pickup;
    calcPrice
      .getPriceList()
      .then(function(result) {
        prices.push(result); // push to array
        console.log(result); // value is retured
      });
  });
  return prices; // returns empty array
}
```

Comment: What does `getPriceList()` look like?

Comment: because `foreach` not waiting for resolving or rejecting promise

Comment: You're doing asynchronous operations in the function but you're returning synchronously (without blocking execution). This doesn't make sense. See the question yours is a duplicate of to understand better how to fix the situation.